# Atmosphere + Long Polling : No message distribution?

Tags: web-applications, spring, async, real-time

I'm experiencing a strange behavior with Atmosphere + Long Polling.

I'd like to have a broadcaster per user, so I have registered a broadcaster on resource suspension with id : /user/.
I use Atmosphere on a clustered environnement, so I have configured to use an external broadcaster that use Hazelcast. (No chance for Redis, corporate rigidity).

Everything seems to work, BUT all broadcasted messages never reach the browser.

```
Future<Object> f = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup("/user/foo").broadcast("my lovely message");
f.get()
```

I can see my pending request on each browser (Chrome/ Firefox), but no resume, and no response until the socket timeout to renew the connection.

My environment :

- Servlet 3.0
- JBoss AS7 7.20
- Spring 3.2 + MeteorServlet
- Atmosphere 1.1.0RC1 (same with the most stable version) + jQuery Atmosphere

Comment: Off-topic comment, but how did you make that avatar?